# WooCommerce icons not showing in backend under GAE

Tags: css, google-app-engine, woocommerce

When I run WooCommerce 2.1.6 with WordPress 3.8.1 locally under MAMP everything works as expected, but when I run the same versions with the GoogleAppEngineLauncher v1.9.0, the WooCommerce icons of the WooCommerce font are not showing. Neither next to the menu items WooCommerce and Products, nor on the WooCommerce welcome screen.

All fonts are in place in

```
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/
├── WooCommerce.eot
├── WooCommerce.svg
├── WooCommerce.ttf
├── WooCommerce.woff
├── star.eot
├── star.svg
├── star.ttf
└── star.woff
```

I'm not sure if this is GAE specific. I've set all file and directory permissions to 777 for the sake of testing to no avail. When deploying it to the cloud the problem remains the same.

I've now also added a new section in app.yaml for the font file extensions, but in the app engine logs I now see a 301 followed by a 200. The result still looks the same as before, i.e. the font icons are not being rendered.

```
2014-03-26 23:40:28.993 301    327B 317ms   /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/WooCommerce.ttf
    93.209.186.52 - - [26/Mar/2014:15:40:28 -0700] "GET /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/WooCommerce.ttf HTTP/1.1" 301 327 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36" "elaborate-chess-531.appspot.com" ms=317 cpu_ms=208 cpm_usd=0.000037 instance=00c61b117c3b43b5a1b35e0b88932df4bf005ee7 app_engine_release=1.9.1

2014-03-26 23:40:29.715 200     4KB 509ms   /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/WooCommerce.ttf/
    93.209.186.52 - - [26/Mar/2014:15:40:29 -0700] "GET /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/WooCommerce.ttf/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4589 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36" "elaborate-chess-531.appspot.com" ms=509 cpu_ms=292 cpm_usd=0.000513 instance=00c61b117c3b43b5a1b35e0b88932df4bf005ee7 app_engine_release=1.9.1
```

Any ideas what I might be missing here?

[image: WordPress backend screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No doubt your app.yaml doesn't have routes to these files defined. You probable have a handler defined like this

```
- url: /wp-content/(.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
  static_files: wordpress/wp-content/\1
  upload: wordpress/wp-content/.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif)$
  application_readable: true
```

Add another section below it to cover the fonts etc. Something like

```
- url: /wp-content/(.*\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff))$
  static_files: wordpress/wp-content/\1
  upload: wordpress/wp-content/.*\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff)$
  application_readable: true
```

Have a look for any other paths that are returning 404's and make sure they have a handler defined as well.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I've added the new section. There are no 404 errors in the log, only 200, 301 and 304. I've added some more details to the question, too.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. No more 404s, but still not working. What's strange though is that it first shows a 301 and then a 200. Same URL, but with a trailing slash. Another thing I noticed is that the svg font file shows with 0 kb in the log and is not available if I call the [URL](https://elaborate-chess-531.appspot.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/fonts/WooCommerce.svg) in the browser.

Comment: Today I made a fresh install and can confirm that the new font routes section solved the problem. No idea why it didn't during my initial installation, but I'm glad it now works. Thanks again!

Comment: this is giving me could not guess mime type errors. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27699750/some-fonts-dont-work-google-app-engine-wordpress.

The exact same problem I am having

Answer (score 0):

It's normal. I think if i understand your problem, it's a problem of path.
I explain. Woocommerce icon don't work widthout www.
If you domain wordpress path is http://yourdomain.com. It's not good
Change in the database wordpress width http://www.yourdomain.com

You icons be work !